# Passing arguments to compiler and javadoc in gradle

Tags: java, javadoc, gradle, javac

I am trying to provide Gradle as an alternative build system on an existing project. That project makes use of `sun.misc.Unsafe` which leads to warnings like this one:

```
warning: Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
```

To suppress this warning `-XDignore.symbol.file` is passed as an argument to javac and javadoc in the current ant script.

In order to suppress these warnings in Gradle I had to resort to what I feel are 'dirty' hacks that I am not too comfortable with.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    // I only managed to get this working when I forked 
    // and passed 'javac' as an executable
    options.compilerArgs << '-XDignore.symbol.file'
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}


javadoc {
    // These get ignored
    // options.addStringOption('XDignore.symbol.file', null)
    // options.addStringOption('XDignore.symbol.file')

    // This one fails the build - I am assuming it's trying to parse ''
    // options.addStringOption('XDignore.symbol.file')

    // This works, but it's an ugly hack
    options.addStringOption('XDignore.symbol.file', '-quiet')
}
```

Surely there must be a more elegant way that I don't know to achieve this.

Here ( https://gist.github.com/3772416 ) is a more complete example with an accompanying ant script and a sample class that causes the problem.

Thanks

I am running Gradle 1.1

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Tuesday, 31 July 2012 13:24:32 o'clock UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.7.0_07 (Oracle Corporation 23.3-b01)
OS: Linux 3.2.0-30-generic amd64
```

It seems that this is a reasonable worakround at the moment for suppressing these particular warnings. See - http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/passing_arguments_to_compiler_and_javadoc?rfm=1

Comment: Please always state the Gradle version.

Comment: I've added the version information as suggested

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Javadoc, the following might work:

```
javadoc.options.jflags "-XDignore.symbol.file"
```

Regarding Java compilation, it would be good to know if `options.fork = true` and  `options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'` are still required with recent Gradle versions (e.g. 1.2). If yes, please file a problem at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: I have tried using `jFlags` and got a `Unrecognized option: -XDignore.symbol.file`

I have upgraded to Gradle 1.2 and I still need both `options.fork = true` and `options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'`. I have also tried jFlags with 1.2 and got the same result as with 1.1

I'll raise the issue on Gradle forum.

Thanks for help.