# Suppress Java warning "Unsafe is internal proprietary API" in Groovy project build with Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I've have a Groovy project built with Gradle (1.8) in which some Java classes report the following compiler warning message:

```
warning: Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
```

Is there a way to suppress that error message? I've found some answers suggesting to use the javac compiler option `-XDignore.symbol.file` but I'm unable to apply it in the Gradle build when using the Groovy plugin.

Any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `Unsafe`? Avoiding direct dependence on it is a far preferable option if possible.

Comment: It is some legacy code that I do not want/can't change. Thus, I would just switch off that message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to compiler and javadoc in gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554829/passing-arguments-to-compiler-and-javadoc-in-gradle)

Comment: Actually is not duplicate, because the `compilerArgs << '-XDignore.symbol.file'` do not work when using the Groovy joint compilation as in my case.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning

Answer (score 7):

Add following to your gradle.build file

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-XDignore.symbol.file'
    options.fork = true // may not needed on 1.8
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac' // may not needed on 1.8
}
```

fork is required on gradle 1.6, not sure about 1.8 
update: it's still required on 1.8

Comment: All of this is still needed in 1.8/1.9. What it does is to force Gradle into using the command-line compiler. This is necessary because the Java compiler API doesn't support the `-XDignore.symbol.file` option. Note that using the command-line compiler may slow down builds (in particular multi-project builds).

Comment: It is not working. I'm still getting the warning message(s). Since they are produced by the ':compileGroovy' step, should not the compilerArgs applied to the groovy compiler options?

Comment: Actually it worked, but I had to move the Java sources into the src/main/java directory (instead of src/main/groovy).
As a side effect, now the Groovy compilation fails because it do not "see" the java compiled classes.

Comment: You didnt mention that you compile java files with groovy. Why your java files stored in groovy source folder? Gradle builds assume lot of defaults and if you do something strange, you need to say gradle about this.

Comment: Moving the Java sources to a separate folder (let's says `src/main/java` instead of `src/main/groovy`) then the compiler option you suggested works, BUT the groovy compilation fails because it is unable to find the Java classes compiled by the `compileJava` stage.

Comment: You didn't mention that you were using joint compilation. Try to move the sources back and replace `compileJava` with `compileGroovy` above. I'm not completely sure if these options work for joint compilation, but it's worth a try.