# Is option.fork still necessary to set bootClasspath

Tags: java, gradle, javac

To set options in java compiler, it seems that `option.fork = true` was necessary for early versions of gradle but [shouldn't be necessary after gradle 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554829/passing-arguments-to-compiler-and-javadoc-in-gradle) as that answer by Peter Niederwieser suggests.

In gradle 2.2.1, with groovy 2.3.6, I've successfully tested `options.bootClasspath` behavior on several desks **without** `option.fork = true` which seems in contradiction to [gradle documentation for bootClasspath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:bootClasspath)

Why option.fork is necessary for the option `bootClasspath`?